# How to extract specific details from pdf to excel

Tags: java, python, excel, pdf-reader, tabula

**I want to extract specific details from the pdf that has a table format and want to save it to excel using python.**

I have tried to convert the pdf to excel/text using tabula library.

```py
tabula.convert_into("eway.pdf", "output.csv", output_format="csv", pages='all')
```

I have also tried the area parameter but it doesnt help much

```py
tabula.read_pdf("eway.pdf", area=(126,149,212,462), pages=1)
```

I want to extract the highlighted part as shown in the image and save each line in different cells

Comment: You can use a `pdf2html` package to parse your pdf to html which is easier then to read your data to a csv.

Comment: @Kotsas i tried that but the problem is that the pdf contains tables. so it translates row wise. So the html contains all the header first and then its row. I want to extract the data of the table based on the header. For example, if there is a header called product, I want to read the product column and extract all the product it contains. Is this possible?